# Calculating a derivative with dependent variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have two equations $w=x^2+y^2+z^2$
and  $z=x^2+y^2$

Then $x$ is the dependent variable in the question.
I must calculate $dw/dz$ holding $y$ constant using differentials. I do not understand how to calculate this at all. Can someone please show me the process?

Answer (score 1):

Since $z  = x^2 + y^2$, you have that $w = z + z^2$. Then you just apply the derivative and obtain
${\text{d} w}/{\text{d}z} = {\text{d} z}/{\text{d} z} + {\text{d} z^2 }/{ \text{d} z} = 1 + 2z = 1 + 2x^2 + 2y^2$.

Comment: I was able to solve it this way and also by using substitution, but the second part of the problem says to solve it using differentials.

Comment: please define differential: it is not clear to me what you mean

Comment: it is the equation that shows the rate of change of the equation based on the change of the variables in it. 
The change in w= change in x+change in y+….+change in n. 
The coefficients of the differential are the same as those in the gradient vector.